# Limit of probability that a permutation of $\mathcal{S}_n$ has a $k$-cycle is $1 - e^{-1/k}$?

Tags: permutations

Choose a random permutation $\sigma \in \mathcal{S}_n$. What's the probability that it contains a $k$-cycle as you take $n \to \infty$?

I ran a couple examples and it seems to approach $1 - e^{-1/k}$. Can anyone explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permutations are counted by cycles using the exponential generating function

$$
\frac1{1-z}=\exp\log\frac1{1-z}=\exp\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}j\right)\;,
$$

where the $j$-th term corresponds to $j$-cycles (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics)). To count the number of permutations without $k$-cycles, we can drop the $k$-th term to obtain

$$
n![z^n]\exp\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}j-\frac{z^k}k\right)
=
\frac1{1-z}\exp\left(-\frac{z^k}k\right)\;,
$$

where $[z^n]$ denotes extraction of the coefficient of $z^n$. This coefficient is the sum of all coefficients up to $n$ in $\exp(-z^k/k)$. For $n\to\infty$, that becomes the sum of all coefficients, which is the value at $1$, i.e. $\mathrm e^{-1/k}$. Dividing by the number $n!$ of permutations in $S_n$ to obtain the probability for a random permutation not to contain a $k$-cycle cancels the factor $n!$, so the probability tends to $\mathrm e^{-1/k}$, and the complementary probability that a random permutation contains a $k$-cycle tends to $1-\mathrm e^{-1/k}$, in agreement with your results.

Comment: Why do we get a $n![z^n]$ term on the LHS? It seems we just multiply both sides by $\exp(-\frac{z^k}{k})$, no? I'm probably just confused about what's going on here. I'm going to read over it a couple more times.

Comment: @Soke: This is not a term -- as I wrote, $[z^n]$ is notation for extracting the coefficient of $z^n$, it's not a multiplication by $z^n$. The factor $n!$ is part of the definition of an exponential generating function, which counts a sequence $a_n$ using the series $\sum_n\frac{a_n}{n!}z^n$, so $a_n$ is $n!$ times the coefficient of $z^n$ (as opposed to an ordinary generating function, which is the same thing without the factors of $n!$).

Comment: @Soke: I just noticed I'd written $\mathrm e^{-k}$ in several places where it was supposed to be $\mathrm e^{-1/k}$; I fixed that.

Comment: Okay, I think I get more or less what's happening here now. I've never seen EGFs before, so I think that's where my confusing is coming from.

Comment: I worked it out a bit more and understand it a lot better now the intuitino behind the formal power series. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @joriki Nice work. Upvoted. (+1).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: I learned from the master :-)

Comment: These are kind words. The reference is the book by Flajolet and Sedgewick.